# Forced air furnace filter gets wet with water while A/C is ON

Tags: air-conditioning

Noticed lately when it has been extremely hot, and my air conditioner is constantly turned on, that my furnace filter get soaked wet.  Took it out , opened the furnace door to check, but there was no water on the inside of the furnace floor, but only in the slot where the furnace filter slides in.   Have been drying the filter (aftre shutting the system off) and reusing it.   A/C works fine, with super cold air.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Check the condensation drain path from your evaporator for blockage or leaks. There may be a tray with a tube attached. They tend to rust through over the years, but it could be mineral buildup or the result of insects blocking it.

[image]

[Source and read more](http://yourhousewhisperers.com/my-furnace-is-leaking/)

Answer (score 0):

Condensate drainage can get clogged. Check your condensate drainage lines and reservoir.

Comment: Thanks much.  The condensate plug at junction of tray and the drain pipe was heavily clogged.  Blew air in pipe and cleaned the plug.  Problem solved.   How do I check the tray for future, as it is sealed inside the duct ?  Also , how do I check for any rust in heat exchanger, for coming winter months.

Comment: There *should* be a place on the unit where you can view it....usually with a flashlight while lying on your side... I would check it every 3 months. Glad you found it, sir